# pm2 not running my entire exec() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine, pm2

I'm running a Virtual Server which host multiple processes.

I've created a specific user to access specific app running on this server.

So for app_template, I have a app_template_operator that clone repo in `/home/app_template_operator/app_template`.

From this directory, I run a pm2 config file that will run 3 scripts:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'app_template_live',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      cwd: '/home/app_template_operator/app_template',
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      exec_mode: 'cluster', // Or 'fork' based on your preference
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        // Add other environment variables specific to this process
      },
      log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z', // Customize the log date format
    },
    {
      name: 'app_template_scd',
      script: 'server/scripts/scd.js',
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      exec_mode: 'cluster', // Or 'fork' based on your preference
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        // Add other environment variables specific to this process
      },
      log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z', // Customize the log date format
    },
    {
      name: 'app_template_webhook',
      script: 'server/scripts/webhook_3002.js',
      instances: 1,
      cwd: '/home/app_template_operator/app_template',
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      exec_mode: 'cluster', // Or 'fork' based on your preference
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        // Add other environment variables specific to this process
      },
      log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z', // Customize the log date format
    },
  ],
};
```

First is for the app

Second is for the Static Content Delivery

Third is to update app when a push happens on the `live` branch of the repos.

My problem is with the 3rd one:

```
/** @format */

const http = require('http');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: '/home/app_template_operator/app_template/.env.local' });

// Set your GitHub Webhook secret
const GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let body = '';

  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk.toString();
  });

  req.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Request data received.');

    const sig = `sha1=${crypto
      .createHmac('sha1', GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET)
      .update(body)
      .digest('hex')}`;
    const payloadSig = req.headers['x-hub-signature'];

    if (crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(sig), Buffer.from(payloadSig))) {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log('Payload authenticated.');

      if (payload.ref === 'refs/heads/live') {
        console.log('Received push to live branch. Deploying...');

        let deploymentLog = ''; // To collect deployment log messages

        // Function to run the deployment script
        const runDeploymentScript = () => {
          console.log('Running deploy-script.sh...');
          const deployProcess = exec(
            'bash /home/app_template_operator/app_template/server/scripts/deploy-script.sh',
            {
              cwd: '/home/app_template_operator/app_template/',
            },
            (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              const deploymentLog = stdout; // Capture the deployment log

              if (error) {
                const status = 'FAILED';
                console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
                console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                console.log('Deployment failed.');
                console.log('Deployment Log:', deploymentLog); // Log deployment process output
                sendEmail(status, payload, deploymentLog); // Send email with the deployment log
              } else {
                const status = 'SUCCESS';
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
                console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                console.log('Deployed successfully.');
                console.log('Deployment Log:', deploymentLog); // Log deployment process output
                sendEmail(status, payload, deploymentLog); // Send email with the deployment log
              }
            }
          );

          // Collect log messages during the deployment process
          deployProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(data.toString()); // Log deployment process output
          });

          deployProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(data.toString()); // Log deployment process output
          });
        };

        // Usage: Pass a callback function that sends the email when the script is finished
        runDeploymentScript((status) => {
          console.log('Deployment script finished.');
          sendEmail(status, payload, deploymentLog);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Received push to non-live branch. Ignoring...');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Payload not authenticated. Push is ignored');
    }
  });

  res.end('Webhook received.');
});

const PORT = process.env.SERVER_WEBHOOK_GH_PUSH_PORT || 3002;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Webhook server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

// Function to send an email
const sendEmail = (status, payload, deploymentLog) => {
  console.log('Sending email...');

  // Set your email configuration
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
    },
  });

  // Build the email content
  const emailContent = `
    <h1>Deployment Status</h1>
    <p>Status: ${status}</p>
    <p>Branch: ${payload.ref}</p>
  
    <h2>Push Information</h2>
    <p>Pusher: ${payload.pusher.name} (${payload.pusher.email})</p>

    <h2>Commit Details</h2>
    ${payload.commits
      .map(
        (commit) => `
        <h3>Commit ID: ${commit.id}</h3>
        <p>Message: ${commit.message}</p>
        <p>Author: ${commit.author.name} (${commit.author.email})</p>
        <p>Added: ${commit.added.join(', ')}</p>
        <p>Removed: ${commit.removed.join(', ')}</p>
        <p>Modified: ${commit.modified.join(', ')}</p>
      `
      )
      .join('')}

    <h2>Deployment Log</h2>
    <pre>${deploymentLog}</pre>
  `;

  // Email options
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    to: 'samuel.amann@kyvos.me',
    subject: `Deployment Status: ${status} - Branch: ${payload.ref}`,
    html: emailContent,
  };

  // Send the email
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error sending email: ${error}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Email sent: ${info.response}`);
    }
  });
};
```

When I run the script with
`node server/scripts/webhook_3002.js` everything goes according to plan:

Upon trigger, checks if its the right branch, then starts the exec function, running the file, updating the deployment log and finally sending an email depending on resolution of the script.

This is expected behaviour.

But when the script runs through pm2, everything works fine BUT the emails that are not send.

But not at all, not even tries to. I've set console.log all over the place but not one gets triggered.

It runs the deploy-script.sh just fine, pulls correctly the repo, successfully builds the app and restart the pm2 scripts just as expected.

But when it never reaches the sendEmail part.

I've tried everything: hard coding the env variables (have them printed as well, pm2 does access them), giving more permissions, ... nothing works.

pm2 CAN use the sendEmail function as I've tried to fire it before or after the exec function and it worked fine.

But it does not work when its INSIDE the exec function...

Something to do with the asynchronous needs of the exec?
Why does it work when I manually (as the app_template_operator) run the script?

Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Have you print `process.env` to console to verify that you really get your vars? And take a look at pm2 logs (error and out) to find message tat may help?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on answer.
Yes I have check with a console.log and PM2 CAN print ALL the env variables...
I really don't understand but I think it is about the way it treats the code.

I feel like as the code takes to long to finish, the process kind of stop and do not fire following execution of code. It just finishes the one started... Makes sense ?

Comment: Ok, but i mean, have you check the pm2 error logs. They are located in `/<username>/.pm2/logs`. 

You have 2 files once named `xxxx-out.logs` and a second named `xxxxx-error.logs`
Have you check thiese two files?

Comment: I've checked both logs and they're both empty... :
https://api.mclo.gs/1/raw/Ba5JgkG

Comment: I've change few settings, mainly the pm2.config.js file to set the exec_mode to fork (instead of cluster) and at least now it captures the correct logs from the scripts.
Still no clue why it skips the sendEmail part...

I've even notice that, if I run the script in a separate pm2 process (pm2 start server/scripts/webhook_3002.js) directly, it sends the mail.
I thought this would give insight of how to set the default behaviour for the pm2 process... but as I seem not to be able to reproduce it, it confuses me even more.